# using prettyCheckable plugin with knockoutjs 2.1 checked data-binding doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using the prettyCheckable jquery plugin to make my checkboxes and radio buttons look pretty and if I use the data-bind="checked: dateMode" it doesn't work because the plugin hides the actual checkbox and makes it's own override html to pretty up the checkbox/radio, therefore the knockoutjs lib doesn't recognize when I check the radio or checkbox and update the value in the model. I know my code works fine if I don't use prettyCheckable plugin, so don't tell me my model or data binding code is messed up. I tested this.

https://github.com/arthurgouveia/prettyCheckable

Here is my partial view code.

```
<div id="DatesChooser" class="span5 pull-left">
    <h4><i class="icon-calendar"></i>Dates</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="Date" value="All" data-label="All Available" data-bind="checked: dateMode" /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="Date" value="Range" data-label="Range" data-bind="checked: dateMode" />
    <div data-bind="visible: dateMode() == 'Range'">
        <input type="text" id="FromYear" placeholder="1970" /> to
        <input type="text" id="ToYear" placeholder="2012" /><br />
        <div id="Date-Slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <div id="Date-Slider-Bar" class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
            <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a>
            <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 100%;"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my knockout model :

```
function searchVm() {
    var self = this;
    self.dateMode = ko.observable("All");
    self.startSearch = function () { alert(self.dateMode()); };
};
```

And I initialize the prettyCheckable stuff like this :

```
$('input:checkbox').prettyCheckable();
$('input:radio').prettyCheckable();
```

Here is what the code gets rendered as after the prettyCheckable plugin modifies it, notice how the input style is 'display:none' :

```
<div id="DatesChooser" class="span5 pull-left">
    <div class="clearfix prettyradio labelright blue">
        <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: dateMode" data-label="All Available" value="All" name="Date" style="display: none;" checked="checked">
        <a class="checked" href="#"></a>
        <label for="undefined">All Available</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="clearfix prettyradio labelright blue">
        <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: dateMode" data-label="Range" value="Range" name="Date" style="display: none;">
        <a class="" href="#"></a>
        <label for="undefined">Range</label>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: dateMode() == 'Range'" style="display: none;">
        <input id="FromYear" class="placeholder" type="text" placeholder="1970">
to
        <input id="ToYear" class="placeholder" type="text" placeholder="2012">
        <br>
        <div id="Date-Slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <div id="Date-Slider-Bar" class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
            <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%;" href="#"></a>
            <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 100%;" href="#"></a>
            <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty Checkable triggers `change` events on the checkboxes, but Knockout looks for `click` events. This can be fixed with a change in `prettyCheckable.js` lines 46-54. Original:

```
    if (input.attr('checked') !== undefined) {
      input.removeAttr('checked').change();
    } else {
      input.attr('checked', 'checked').change();
    }
```

Changed:

```
    if (window.ko) {
      ko.utils.triggerEvent(input[0], 'click');
    } else {
      input.click();
    }
```

Knockout also won't work if you use jQuery's `click` trigger function. You must use Knockout's `triggerEvent` as above.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/4cX48/

Comment: I will take a look soon. I have another project I am working on to so I will try as soon as I can.

Comment: This didn't work. I will try the above answer soon when I have time, but it will require a lot more code than your idea.

Comment: Okay. I decided to actually test it. I've edited my answer with a working version.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out as soon as I can. The author of prettyCheckable could modify his code too for others.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong here. Pretty Checkable library works that way.

It finds the input dom hide them and put dynamic a and label tag instead of that input. If you want to find that input is checked or not you need to examine class of dynamically added a tag ( Class ="checked"). Not the orginal input tag.

You need to write a binding for prettycheckable and observe the a tag's class. Then change the checked value of your binding according to class of that a tag.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Comment: I will try this and give you a answered check once it works. But I think you are right, can't believe I didn't think of this, it was on the tip of my toungek, but I am still fairly new to knockoutjs.Once I get it working I will post the code answer here.

Comment: Your way could work too, but it requires a lot more code and I think the creator of pretty checkable should modify his library to support the major js frameworks because they are widely used now and people want to use them with this plugin and bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael's modification to prettyCheckbox *mostly* worked, but if your viewModel already has a selection made when you load, prettyCheckbox will NOT recognize it because it is looking for the "checked" **attribute** while knockout/plain vanilla html will mark the checkbox as checked via a **property**.

in prettyCheckbox change:

```
var isChecked = el.attr('checked') !== undefined ? 'checked' : '';
```

to

```
var isChecked = el.prop('checked') == true ? 'checked' : '';
```

Also, it is important to know that if you modify your knockout viewmodel property in code, it will NOT be reflected in prettyCheckbox because I'm not aware of a way to subscribe (in javascript, not knockout) to a change in a property.